# First line every time I open VSCode integrated terminal (eval):1: no such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, jetbrains-ide, rust-cargo, jetbrains-toolbox

Only in VSCode every time I open the integrated terminal I get

> `(eval):1: no such file or directory: Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts:/Users/$HOME/.cargo/bin:/Users/$HOME/.local/bin`

I can't seem to locate what exactly the problem is. I've checked those folders, reinstalled all JetBrains products, reinstalled VSCode, reinstalled cargo, and I still get this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: One of your shell startup files (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.zshrc`...) is doing something odd with the `PATH`, I suspect.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I commented out each line related to these folders individually in these startup files and then all of them together and none of the times was I able to solve it... I suspect it has something to do with the fact that there is a macOS directory called "Application Support" and it's missing an escape character somewhere where it's referenced, perhaps in a JetBrains config or script. That's why you see "Support" and not "Application Support". That's my best guess to it anyways. Is there any way I can nuke my setup or environment to start from scratch?

Comment: I don't really know if this is a solution but in JetBrains Toolbox I un-toggled "Generate shell scripts" and I no longer get the error every time I open vscode.